# How does inserting new SSD will influence perfomance?

Tags: linux, ssd

I have old 120GB SSD

```
 lsscsi -s
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      GOODRAM          10.8  /dev/sda    120GB
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      TOSHIBA DT01ACA1 A750  /dev/sdb   1.00TB
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222AB  SB00  /dev/sr0
```

As I understand I have 4 slots on my motherboard

```
lsscsi -H
[0]    ahci          
[1]    ahci          
[2]    ahci          
[3]    ahci
```

I bought Crucial MX500

If I insert it to the last free slot,how will it take on my operation?
 Or maybe it is better option to to change the old SSD with the new one,in that case I have to install the new Ubuntu again?

Comment: if you have enough ram turn off swap partition, regularly using swap can decrease ssd storage limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you want to install your operating system and leave the files you use the most on the new (and faster) SSD.

You can either do a new, fresh install or transfer your existing one: in this case, you can use something like [Clonezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741723/moving-entire-linux-installation-to-another-drive).